# Vuex watcher wrongly firing twice

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, components, vuex

i've been searching for 2 hours now, i have zero idea what i'm doing wrong.. hope someone can help me:

basically it's pretty easy. i have a reusable component for Recaptchas. 
the element in question is a textfield in a popup dialog for "forgot password" (over the login mask)

the basic idea to handle the varying captchas (because there are two on the same page) is:

- i have a vuex field for every possible captcha, inited to `null`
- for each form submit button, i trigger a mutation that sets the captcha field to `0`
- then i have setup watchers in the recaptcha component which listen to changes, and `if === 0`, start evaluating the captcha
- then `onValidated`, call a mutation that saves the result to vuex. another watcher with `if(newVal)` then submits the whole thing.

in my theory, this works without a problem. i remember it already has worked at some point in the past (or i just didn't notice the double submit), but now i made some changes, and it behaves really strange.

to be precise: i click the button once, everything works fine, BUT one watcher fires twice, even though it shouldn't at all.
everything before fires ONCE, only that watcher fires twice, even when i did

```
if (!this.running) {
            this.running = true
            console.log('forgot watcher 2')
            this.$refs.recaptcha.execute()
        }
```

but it doesn't work either. it seems to run them at the exact same time, which doesn't make sense to me

the console output is this:

```
submit
verify forgot captcha
0
forgot watcher 2
0
forgot watcher 2
verified
forgot captcha verified 03AOLTBLTP...............
forgot watcher
verified
forgot watcher
```

so in an easy-to-follow way:

- click at login.vue
- mutation sets value to 0
- watcher in recaptcha.vue notices and starts evaluation (this one wrongly fires twice)
- if verified, `verifyCaptcha()` in recaptcha.vue stores to vuex

my files are as follows:

### login.vue

```
<template>
  <v-form
    @submit.prevent="twoFaRequired ? sendTwoFa() : verifyLoginCaptcha()"
  >
    // ...
   <recaptcha />
    // ...
    <v-layout>
        <form>
           // ...
           <recaptcha />
           <v-btn
              color="primary"
              :loading="forgotLoading"
              :disabled="successful || forgotLoading || $v.$invalid"
              @click.native.stop.prevent="verifyForgotCaptcha"
            >Reset Password</v-btn>

//...
  methods: {
    verifyForgotCaptcha() {
      console.log('submit')
      this.$store.commit('user/VERIFY_FORGOT_CAPTCHA')
    },
//...
  watch: {
    forgotCaptcha(newVal, oldVal) {
      if (newVal) {
        console.log('forgot watcher')
        this.sendForgotEmail()
      }
    },
//...
    forgotCaptcha() {
      return this.$store.state.user.forgotCaptcha
    },
```

### mutations.js

```
//...
  VERIFY_FORGOT_CAPTCHA(state) {
    console.log('verify forgot captcha')
    state.forgotCaptcha = 0
  },
  FORGOT_CAPTCHA_VERIFIED(state, payload) {
    console.log('forgot captcha verified', payload)
    state.forgotCaptcha = payload
  },
//...
```

### recaptcha.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="d-flex justify-center">
    <vue-recaptcha
      ref="recaptcha"
      :sitekey=siteKey
      :loadRecaptchaScript="true"
      size="invisible"
      @verify="verifyCaptcha">
    </vue-recaptcha>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import VueRecaptcha from 'vue-recaptcha'
  import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

  export default {
    data: () => ({
      running: false,
      usage: '',
      siteKey: 'xxxxxxx'
    }),
    components: { VueRecaptcha },
    computed: {
      ...mapGetters([
        'user'
      ]),
    //...
      isForgotCaptcha() {
        return this.$store.getters['user/forgotCaptcha']
      }
    },
    methods: {
      verifyCaptcha(response) {
        console.log('verified')
    //...
          if (this.usage === 'forgot')        this.$store.commit('user/FORGOT_CAPTCHA_VERIFIED', response)
        this.usage = ''
        this.$refs.recaptcha.reset()
      }
    },
    watch: {
    //...
      isForgotCaptcha(newVal) {
        if (newVal === 0) {
          console.log('forgot watcher 2')
          this.usage = 'forgot'
          this.$refs.recaptcha.execute()
        }
      },
    }
  };
</script>
```

if you need any more info/code, please feel free to ask. i hope anyone can tell me what i'm doing wrong. i'm going mad here.
thank you!

Answer (score 3):

In `login.vue` you have two instances of `<recaptcha>`. Each of these will have its own set of watchers, they aren't shared. Similarly they each have their own computed property `isForgotCaptcha`.

When `user/forgotCaptcha` changes it will change the `isForgotCaptcha` property of both components, triggering each of their watchers.

Setting `this.running` will only set that property for one of the `recaptcha` components, it won't have any impact on the other.

Comment: wow ok, that sounds reasonable. interesting! that IS probably the problem, thank you! and that explains why my guards had NO effect, and those watchers seemed to run at the same time! do you have an idea how i can separate them? or how i can make this work?